# php regular expression not matching correctly

Tags: php, regex

This is a simplified example, but when I run this code the first does not match as it should. It only matches the first part and nothing else.
The other two occurrences match properly so I have no idea why the first wouldn't.

```
$str = 'What is 5 plus three?What is 4 plus three?What is 4 plus two?';

$replacees = [
'/What is (.*?) plus two\?/',
'/What is (.*?) plus three\?/',
];
$replacers = [
'I know $1 and 2.',
'I know $1 and 3.',
];

print_r( preg_replace($replacees, $replacers, $str) );
```

The results from that are:

I know 5 plus three?I know 4 and 3.What is 4 and 2.

But I'm expecting:

I know 5 and 3.I know 4 and 3.I know 4 and 2.

Comment: The regex engine works from left to the right. Since the first "What is" matches, `.*?` will match all the string until "plus two?".

Comment: you have only digits to replace ?

Comment: @casimir How is it replacing the second one then also?

Comment: @HalayemAnis No, this is just a simple example to isolate the issue.

Comment: i've got it, see my answer :)

Comment: Test with only the first pattern, you will understand.

Comment: @Robbie check the solution that I gave. I think you were on the right track all you needed was to just flip both the array once.

Answer (score 2):

Hi All what you did was correct just flip the code as I have shown here.

```
<?
 $str = 'What is 5 plus three?What is 4 plus three?What is 4 plus two?';

$replacees = [
'/What is (.*?) plus three\?/',
'/What is (.*?) plus two\?/',

];
$replacers = [
 'I know $1 and 3.',
 'I know $1 and 2.',

];

print_r( preg_replace($replacees, $replacers, $str) );
```

I just flipped off the code and this is working now.

Comment: While this does work, I'd rather not have to worry about positions, since my example is really a simplified one to make understanding the issue easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should make global searching and as i see you changed last number word, so the code is:

```
/(?:What is ([\d])* plus (?:[\w]+)\?)/g
```

Of course you can make array of one, two, etc and replace it. Example:

```
$arrayN = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>'3');
```

Then change the expression like:

```
/(?:What is ([\d])* plus ([\w]+)\?)/g
```

and add to replace string:

I know **$1** and **$2**.

All word numbers change to numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO Dmitry :) +1 for your first answer, bravo :)

Comment: While that seems to be working. How would I do something similar that matches every character?

 For example if I had: 'What is 5five plus three?What is 4four plus three?What is 4 plus two?'

Comment: See thу text below:
<?
 $str = 'What is 5 plus three?What is 4 plus three?What is 4 plus two?';
$arrayNymbers = array('one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'three'=>3, 'four'=>4, 'five'=>5, 'six'=>6, 'seven'=>7, 'eight'=>8, 'nine'=>9, 'zero'=>0);

$replacees = "/(?:What is ([\d])* plus ([\w]+)\?)/g";

$replacers = 'I know $1 and '.$arrayNumbers[$2].'.';

print_r(preg_replace($replacees, $replacers, $str) );

Try it